# Vue pass value from creative div to new Vue compoennt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The question is. I am using Vue into simple html page. In one place I inject Vue via `<div id="app"></div>`. So can I some how pass value via data attribute or any other way into new Vue element that will be created here? By the way after Vue work my div to which I am connecting will be replaced by root Vue element. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to initialize Vue instance property `el` not with element id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood a thing.
If you don't need your data being reactive you may use `$options`:

```
let someData = {...}

new Vue({
  el: rootComponentElement,
  someKeyValue: someData,
  render: h => h(rootComponent)
})
```

and then call it via `$root.$options.someKeyValue`

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. Also I have found another solution. In my case the I wrote some form with Vue and simply inject it into html page. Vue is not used anywhere more. But after it has turned out that my Vue component needs to get some data that can't be accessed from api call. My solution was to wrap div#app with another div and pass all necessary values to data attr. Then in Vue component  in it's store get values by this.$root.parentNode